# Is there a way to convert steam.map() individual output to list

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains comma separated values as an individual element. like:

```java
   List<String> personOutputList=new ArrayList<>();
   personOutputList.add("nexus 9k, nexus 9000,n9k");
   personOutputList.add( "nexus 7k, nexus 7000,n7k");
   personOutputList.add("nexus 9000");
   personOutputList.add("utility issue");
   personOutputList.add("network availability issue");
   personOutputList.add("nexus 7000");
   personOutputList.add("nexus 9k issue");
```

Is it possible to convert comma separated elements into part of separate elements list like:

> [nexus 9k, nexus 9000,n9k, nexus 7k, nexus 7000,n7k, nexus 9000, utility issue, network availability issue, nexus 7000, nexus 9k issue]

```java
outputSet=outputSet.stream()
  .map(item->item.split(","))
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

But it returns String[] String array, I want to be as List element

> [nexus 9k, nexus 9000,n9k, nexus 7k, nexus 7000, n7k, nexus 9000, utility issue, network availability issue, nexus 7000, nexus 9k issue]

I need output like this:
Set contains: [nexus 7000, nexus 7k, nexus 7000, n7k, nexus 9k, n9k, nexus 9000, nexus 9k issue, utility issue, network availability issue]

Not like this: 
Set contains what? : [[nexus 7k,  nexus 7000, n7k], [nexus 9k,  nexus 9000, n9k]]

Comment: If you want a list, then let your stream expression be ending with `.collect(Collectors.toList());`, but for unique values, use a `Set`.

Comment: Did you want to have duplicates in your output (as "nexus 9000" appears twice)? If you did, why did you create a `Set`, which doesn't allow duplicates?

Comment: No I wanted an unique values, will edit my question

Answer (score 3):

Your `.map(item->item.split(","))` step transforms a `Stream<String>` to a `Stream<String[]>`. Since you map each element into multiple elements, you should use `flatMap` in order to get a flat `Stream<String>` of all these elements, which can later be collected into a `Set`.

It looks like you want a `Set` of all unique elements, after splitting the comma separated `String`s:

```
Set<String> outputSet = 
    personOutputList.stream()
                    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or, if you want to make sure you get a `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<String> outputSet = 
    personOutputList.stream()
                    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not known about flatMap. It helped me a lot.